# What is the chemical mechanism by which PcP(c) is converted to PcP(Sc) in Fatal Familial Insomnia

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-genetics, human-genetics

I know the gene PRNP and it's location.  There’s a mutation at codon 178 (asparagine found instead of normal aspartic acid) on the prion protein gene (also found in fCJD) and more uniquely there is a the presence of a methionine at position 129.  My question is how PcP(Sc) converts normal PcP(C) into the mutated destructive form, and whether or not this is a reversible process.